# Change the main/root page to a custom page

Tags: magento2, home

How can I change the root/main page of Magento 2 Luma theme to a page of my design? and how to move the root/main page to `http://127.0.0.1/OldRootPage`?

please use simple detailed words ... I'm not deep in this :)

Answer (score 0):

The main page of Magento 2 is a cms page.
Log in the admin, go to Content->Pages, search for the page with the identifier `home` and edit it.
Change the identifier to `old-root-page`.
Then create a new page with the identifier `home` with your own content and save it.

Comment: By doing what you suggest, I am changing the URL of the Home page from http://127.0.0.1/home  to http://127.0.0.1/old-root-page ... this is not what I want... I meant be root page, which is the page that opens when I just enter in the URL address http://127.0.0.1 ... I want this to open when I write http://127.0.0.1/old-root-page, and if I just entered http://127.0.0.1 to open my new custom page